# changing the signs of the harmonic series so that it is still divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

While studying Knopp's book and solutions to an interesting problem here:
[changing the signs of the harmonic series so that it converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600519/changing-the-signs-of-the-harmonic-series-so-that-it-converges?rq=1)
and here:
[Change of signs in harmonic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742643/change-of-signs-in-harmonic-series), the following question appeared in my mind and I can't solve it, despite trying for over a week:

Let $\varepsilon_n$ be the sequence of signs (i.e. $1$ or $-1$) and $E(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\varepsilon_n$.
In the Knopp's problem discussed above, $E(N)=O(N)$.

Is it possible to have $\frac{E(N)}{N}\to 0$, while $\sum\frac{\varepsilon_n}{n}$ divergent?

Comment: Summation by parts and E(N) 
approx  $n/log(n+3)$  do the job.

Comment: What's the idea here? How to define signs to obtain $E(N)=O(\frac{n}{\ln n})$ ? Please, explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably very simple artificial construction of $E(N)$ with the desired properties but here is a fast way to make a sequence with $E(N) = \Theta(\frac{N}{\log(N)})$.

Let $\epsilon_n=1$ if $n$ is even or prime, and $-1$ otherwise.
Then $$E(N) = \frac{N}{2} + \pi(N) + \delta_N - [N - (\frac{N}{2} + \pi (N)+\delta_N)] = 2\pi(N) + 2\delta_N$$ where $|\delta_N|\le 2$ is bounded. By Prime Number Theorem, $\frac{E(N)}{N} \sim \frac{2}{\log N}\rightarrow 0$.

Now by Abel summation formula, $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\epsilon_n}{n}=\frac{E(N)}{N} + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{E(n)}{n(n+1)}$. As $\frac{E(N)}{N}$ converges, it's enough to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{E_n}{n(n+1)}$ diverges. But $\frac{E_n}{n(n+1)}\sim \frac{2}{(n+1)\log(n)}$ and the latter diverges by integral test. The desired follows by limit comparison test.

If we chooose $\epsilon_n$ by flipping a fair coin, by the (strong) law of large numbers, $\frac{E(N)}{N}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely. It's interesting to know what's the probability that $\sum \frac{\epsilon_n}{n}$ converges. By Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law, the probability is either $0$ or $1$, but I don't know which case it is.

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar with Prime Number Theorem, but the last part of your solution (almost surely convergence, Kolmogorov's law) is high above my current level. Is there maybe an easier way to obtain just $\frac{E(N)}{N}\to 0$, not forcing this particular asymptotics?